# Upload video with TwitterKit on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, upload

I'm trying to upload a video via the iOS TwitterKit (latest version). Uploading an image works fine, initializing the video upload as well (receiving a media_id), but I'm getting an Auth error Error `Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=32 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"` when trying to upload my first chunk.

Here's part of my code:

```
let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+multipartBoundary
let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", parameters: params, error: nil) as! NSMutableURLRequest
request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPBody = Network.sharedInstance.bodyDataWithVideoData(videoData!)
Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request, completion: { (_, data, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil || data == nil {
        println("error attaching twitter video upload: \(error)")
    } else {
        println("successfully uploaded video chunk")
        println(data)
    }
})
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What solution have you found? Do you have an up to date answer to post?

Comment: See my answer below. Use "media" with base64 to attach the video data.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did use this solution but it did not work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248965/ios-swift-how-to-post-a-video-to-twitter This is the code I used but I can't figure out why it's not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31259870/793146

Turns out that attaching "media" with the base64 string of the video fixes the issue (as opposed to attaching a multipart body).

Comment: can you please give me sample