# Attach GIF to TWTRComposer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-fabric

In my iOS app, I would like to enable users to tweet GIFs.

I have a working TWTRComposer and tried attaching a GIF by using the SetImage method:

```
[composer setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.localGifURL]]];
```

The image then appears in the composer view, but when the image gets posted to Twitter, it's a static image rather than a GIF.

**Is it possible to attach a GIF to a tweet created with TWTRComposer?**

**Edit**

I tried integrating this library to create an animated UIImage:

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Updating my code, I have the following:

```
[composer setImage:[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:self.localGifURL]];
```

But this still results in a static image on Twitter.

**Edit #2**

One other observation - if I save the GIF to my phone and try to share it on Twitter directly from the Photo library (which opens up what looks to be a TWTRComposer window), it posts as an image, not a GIF.  Which leads me to that you may not be able to attach a GIF to a TWTRComposer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question a while ago but finally got around to implementing this feature.

TWTRComposer still doesn't support adding anything but images, so I used the media/upload REST API as suggested.  I am able to tweet both GIFs and Videos.  Before tweeting either media, I create a custom UIAlertView that lets someone composer a tweet:

[image]

Then when they tap the tweet button, a GIF gets tweeted if it's small enough; otherwise, a video is tweeted.

Resulting GIF tweet: https://twitter.com/spinturntable/status/730609962817294336

Resulting Video tweet: https://twitter.com/spinturntable/status/730609829128081408

Here is how I implemented this feature (lots of help from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/31259870/1720985).

**Create the initial UIAlertView for composing the tweet message:**

```
-(IBAction)tweet:(id)sender{
    // check if the person has twitter
    if([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]){
        // first, show a pop up window for someone to customize their tweet message, limited to 140 characters
        UIAlertView *tweetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Compose Tweet"
                                                             message:nil
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        tweetAlert.tag = TAG_TWEET;
        tweetTextView = [UITextView new];
        [tweetTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        CGRect frame = tweetTextView.frame;
        frame.size.height = 500;
        tweetTextView.frame = frame;

        [tweetTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

        tweetTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 10, 10);

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(limitTextView:) name:@"UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification" object:tweetTextView];


        [tweetTextView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"tweetText"], self.setShareURL]];
        [tweetAlert setValue:tweetTextView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
        [tweetAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Tweet"];
        [tweetAlert show];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                        message:@"Please log in with your Twitter account to tweet!"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

**Then detect the UIAlertView Tweet (I add a UIAlertViewDelegate):**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   if(alertView.tag == TAG_TWEET){
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {

            UIAlertView *tweetStartAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                            message:@"Tweeting..."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [tweetStartAlert show];

            // get client
            __block TWTRAPIClient *client = [[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient];
            __block NSString *mediaID;

            NSString *text = [tweetTextView text]; // get tweet text
            NSLog(@"text: %@", text);
            NSData *mediaData;
            NSString *mediaLength;
            NSString *mediaType;
            NSString* url = @"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";

            // if this is a single spin set, tweet the gif
            if([self.setSpins count] ==1){
                NSLog(@"tweeting GIF with url %@", self.gifURL);
                mediaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.gifURL]];
                mediaLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", mediaData.length];
                mediaType = @"image/gif";
            }else if([self.setSpins count] > 1){
                // multi-spin set - tweet the video
                NSLog(@"tweeting video with url %@", self.videoURL);
                mediaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.videoURL]];
                mediaLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", mediaData.length];
                mediaType = @"video/mp4";
            }

            NSError *error;
            // First call with command INIT
            __block NSDictionary *message =  @{ @"status":text,
                                                @"command":@"INIT",
                                                @"media_type":mediaType,
                                                @"total_bytes":mediaLength};

                NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:url parameters:message error:&error];
                [client sendTwitterRequest:preparedRequest completion:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){

                    if(!error){
                        NSError *jsonError;
                        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                              JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                              options:0
                                              error:&jsonError];

                        mediaID = [json objectForKey:@"media_id_string"];
                        NSError *error;

                        NSString *mediaString = [mediaData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

                        // Second call with command APPEND
                        message = @{@"command" : @"APPEND",
                                    @"media_id" : mediaID,
                                    @"segment_index" : @"0",
                                    @"media" : mediaString};

                        NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:url parameters:message error:&error];

                        [client sendTwitterRequest:preparedRequest completion:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){

                            if(!error){
                                client = [[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient];
                                NSError *error;
                                // Third call with command FINALIZE
                                message = @{@"command" : @"FINALIZE",
                                            @"media_id" : mediaID};

                                NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:url parameters:message error:&error];

                                [client sendTwitterRequest:preparedRequest completion:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){

                                    if(!error){
                                        client = [[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient];
                                        NSError *error;
                                        // publish video with status
                                        NSLog(@"publish video!");
                                        NSString *url = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
                                        NSMutableDictionary *message = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:text,@"status",@"true",@"wrap_links",mediaID, @"media_ids", nil];
                                        NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:url parameters:message error:&error];

                                        [client sendTwitterRequest:preparedRequest completion:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){
                                            if(!error){
                                                NSError *jsonError;
                                                NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      error:&jsonError];
                                                NSLog(@"%@", json);

                                                [tweetStartAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

                                                UIAlertView *tweetFinishedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                                                          message:@"Tweeted!"
                                                                                                         delegate:self
                                                                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                [tweetFinishedAlert show];
                                                double delayInSeconds = 1.5;
                                                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                                                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                                                    [tweetFinishedAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                                                });

                                                [self logShare:@"twitter"];

                                            }else{
                                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                            }
                                        }];
                                    }else{
                                        NSLog(@"Error command FINALIZE: %@", error);
                                    }
                                }];

                            }else{
                                NSLog(@"Error command APPEND: %@", error);
                            }
                        }];

                    }else{
                        NSLog(@"Error command INIT: %@", error);
                    }

                }];
            }
        }
    }
```

Some extra things: I focus the UITextView when the Compose Tweet Alert appears:

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    if(alertView.tag == TAG_TWEET){
        NSLog(@"tweetAlertView appeared");
        [tweetTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Here's how I check whether the UITextView has less than 140 characters:

```
- (void)limitTextView:(NSNotification *)note {
    int limit = 140;
    if ([[tweetTextView text] length] > limit) {
        [tweetTextView setText:[[tweetTextView text] substringToIndex:limit]];
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful to others as it took me a long time to piece everything together.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that the TWTRComposer currently supports animated GIF or video attachments. I think you'd have to call the `media/upload` REST API endpoint directly to post the attachment, and then use the `statuses/update` method to attach them to a Tweet.

Comment: thanks for your help – do you happen to have an example of how to do this?

Comment: @scientiffic Here is an example of posting a video using the REST API.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259869/share-video-on-twitter-with-fabric-api-without-composer-ios/

Comment: @john81 thanks for this link!  I'm guessing you need to create a custom window for people to type in the text of their tweet?

Comment: @scientiffic Yes, you have to create all the UI yourself.  I tried to use Twitter's SDK Fabric to do this but on iOS it does not support animated GIF or video, just images.

Comment: The problem with using the REST API is you miss out on some of the benefits the composer offers such as username suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I just built an app that had GIF functionality and needed to be able to post to Twitter. Unfortunately their composer doesn't work with GIFs (I'm 99.9999% sure and if you get it working somehow, let me know).

My solution was actually to, if the user chose to share on Twitter, convert the GIF to a 10 second video that just had the GIF on repeat (my GIFs were always 2 seconds in duration).

I managed to do it using AVAssetWriterInput and AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. It also gave me a fool proof way to post to other social media outlets as many of them don't support GIFs through the composer (Messenger?).

Here's how you can share a video/GIF/any other media type on any shareable platform.

Make sure your view controller responds to the UIActivityItemSource protocol:

```
@interface MyCustomViewController () <UIActivityItemSource>
```

Then, I'll assume you have some method called when you want to share:

```
- (void)methodCalledToShare {
    //Create an activity view controller
    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self] applicationActivities:nil];
    //decide what happens after it closes (optional)
    [activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    }];
    //present the activity view controller
    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

Then you'll need to have this method pertaining to the protocol we conformed to earlier:

```
//This is an example for if you want to have different data sent based on which app they choose.
//I have an NSURL pointing to a local video in "videoUrl"
//And I have NSData of a GIF in "gifData"
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    id item;
    //If it's Facebook, send a video
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook])
        item = self.videoUrl;
    //if its Twitter, send a GIF
    else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter])
        item = self.gifData;
    //if its mail, send a GIF
    else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail])
        item = self.gifData;
    //If it's text, send a GIF
    else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage])
        item = self.gifData;
    //If it's Facebook Messenger, send a video
    else if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.Messenger.ShareExtension"])
        item = self.videoUrl;
    //Just default to a video
    else
        item = self.videoUrl;
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - in my app, I actually have both a video and a GIF that I can post to twitter.  But I don't see an option to add anything but an image to TWTRComposer.  How did you upload a video?

Comment: wow, thank you!  I will try this out first and then mark the answer if it works.

Comment: So I just read through your code - but I still don't understand how you use the video to compose a tweet.  Once you have self.videoURL, how do you use that to share to Twitter?

Comment: The share sheet recognizes that there's a file at that local URL and uses that data in its share.

Comment: Are you using the media/upload from the REST API? https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload

Comment: No, I am using exactly what I posted above. Check out my app, HypnoHuman (excuse how ridiculous and weird of an app it is) http://appstore.com/hypnohuman. You'll see how i do the sharing there.

Comment: hm, I see now.  I would prefer not to use the UIActivityViewController because it adds an extra step in which the user must select which application to share to.  In my app currently, there are direct tweet and fb post buttons.  thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Gotcha. Well just remember that as your app scales and content needs to get shared to other platforms, it might be best to have one share button that brings up the UIActivityViewController. It's what it's there for and aligns with Apple design guidelines.

Comment: one last question - was there a way you could get the video to loop like a GIF?

Comment: I'm revisiting this post and tried adding a local video to the share items, but this does not reveal Twitter as a possible application to share the video.  It does show Facebook, messenger, and other apps, which is successfully attaches the video to.  Just wondering if you were able to tweet videos using this method and if you formatted it a certain way.

Comment: I was using GIF for Twitter posts. I'm not sure if it Twitter share extension supports video...

Comment: ah ok, when I try to add a GIF, it gets posted as an image.  Is there any special formatting you had to do?