# How do I upload video in a tweet in an iOS app using XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, twitter

I am new to iOS development and need to make a change to an iOS app I'm taking over to add video to a tweet.  My current app UI allows the user to type in text for a tweet but I would be changing that to allow them to pick a video to upload along with the tweet similar to how the Twitter app works.

I see the Twitter API supports uploading video but I haven't been able to find any good examples on how to accomplish this using XCode and Objective-C.  Any recommended approaches or tool kits I can leverage to accomplish this?

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to roll my own solution. Check out my project https://github.com/mtrung/TwitterVideoUpload.

- Light-weight due to using built-in Apple's Social framework to keep things light. No need to add extra frameworks such as TwitterKit and Fabric.
- Support chunk upload.
- Built-in support for user's credential retrieval

Comment: Great initiative @Trung! There is no documentation or tutorials on how to do this.. Have you been able to translate your solution to swift or do you know some swift solution? I did not receive answers to my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248965/ios-swift-how-to-post-a-video-to-twitter

Comment: The document is right at github page.
   [[TwitterVideoUpload instance] setVideo:filename];
   [[TwitterVideoUpload instance] upload:^(NSString* errorString) { ... }];
About Swift porting, I didn't get time to do it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the -1 that was helpful.  So thought I found the answer with Fabric (https://get.fabric.io/).  The Android side supports image and video upload with a tweet but the iOS side does not (image only).  It looks like you have to roll your own solution including building a video picker.  Then you can use the Twitter REST API to upload the video.  Not exactly what I was hoping for but it is doable.

This link shows Objective C and Swift code to do the video upload [Share video on Twitter with Fabric API without composer iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259869/share-video-on-twitter-with-fabric-api-without-composer-ios).

Comment: @Sam, not yet but I haven't had a chance to get back this problem yet.  I'm going to try Trung's answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @Sam, Trung's solution works so if you can get it converted to Swift you should be set.