# Programatically upload a video to Youtube

Tags: ios, google-api, youtube-api

I am currently trying to programmatically upload a video from an iOS device to Youtube, but all of the information I am finding is incredibly dated.

I have explored the Google API Cocoapod, but the documentation around using it is rather weak, so I could not find a good starting point.

Other answers on here lead off to four year old projects that are now broken.

Hoping someone can point me to a current example, tutorial or other documentation on how to upload through iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this but I m sure following link will help you.

[1.Upload Videos to YouTube with iPhone custom App](http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/)

[2.Uploading Video with iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065628/uploading-video-with-iphone/1243903#1243903)

[3.YouTube Data API.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel)

[4. Upload Video on you tube.](https://recalll.co/app/?q=ios%20-%20How%20to%20upload%20video%20programmatically%20from%20iPhone%20app%20to%20youtube?)